# How to handle item release event in sortable accordian?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery UI sortable accordian, how do I handle the item release event?
I tried this:

```
$('#accordion').mousedown(function() {
    alert('Handler for .mousedown() called.');
});
```

But the result is not correct. The item is always sticking to the mouse... On mouse down, the popup shows, and if you click ok, the item is still sticking to the mouse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>

        <style>
        /* IE has layout issues when sorting (see #5413) */
        .group { zoom: 1 }
        </style>
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#accordion" )
                .accordion({
                    header: "> div > h3"
                })
                .sortable({
                    axis: "y",
                    handle: "h3",
                    stop: function( event, ui ) {
                        // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
                        // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
                        ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
                    }
                });
        });


        function show_progress() {
            var items = $('.group', '#accordion');
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i+=1) {
                alert(items[i].innerHTML);
            }
        }


        </script>

        <div id="accordion">
            <div class="group">
                <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Edit Item</a>
                    <span class="svr_rlv_url"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Edit Item</a>
                    <span class="svr_rlv_url"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Edit Item</a>
                    <span class="svr_rlv_url"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <a href="#">Edit Item</a>
                    <span class="svr_rlv_url"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br/>

        <a href="#" onclick="show_progress();">CLICK</a>

        <script>
            $('#accordion').mousedown(function() {
              alert('Handler for .mousedown() called.');
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `the item is still sticking to the mouse` what do you mean by this? can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure you are not talking about drag/drop here?

Comment: I added the whole code above. I couldn't get it to work on jsfiddle, not sure how to use it...

Comment: @david, its the jquery UI sortable accordian
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not alert in the middle of a script, this is what happens in the script:

- Mouse down - item gets draggable
- alert - javascript PAUSES
- You release your mouse to click the ok, but javascript does not know this because the script is paused
- when the alert is closed, javascript still thinks you are holding your mouse button down, so the item sticks to your mouse.

Just remove the alert and do `console.log('Handler for .mousedown() called.');` instead

Comment: oh yes i forgot it needs to be mouseup

Answer (score 0):

Your alert inside of a mousedown is messing up the script. You don't need to look for mousedown though anyways, you already have a stop callback function attached to your sortable initializer. Just add your code in there by looking for the `ui.item` as that is the current dragged item.

I've set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nQ4Zq/